# How to change size of an MKMapView in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview

I can't seem to change the size of my MKMapView in Swift. How would one go on about it?

I've tried two different methods but without any luck:

```
var rect: CGRect = self.view.frame;
rect.origin.y = 0;
self.mapView.frame = rect;
```

and one where I used constraints and autolayout but it made the app crash. Any ideas?

EDIT:

When I write this code it doesn't crash but writes some warnings in the output:

```
    let height = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height
    let width = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width

    let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: mapView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: width)
    self.view.addConstraint(widthConstraint)

    let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: mapView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: height)
    self.view.addConstraint(heightConstraint)
```

The output says:

> 2016-03-09 18:43:02.697 Map[19782:3177712] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
>       Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
>       Try this: 
>           (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
>           (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
>   (
>       "",
>       ""
>   )
>
> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
>
> Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints
>   to catch this in the debugger. The methods in the
>   UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in
>    may also be helpful. Message from debugger:
>   Terminated due to signal 15

I don't really understand this, any ideas?

Comment: You said it makes the app crash, what does the console say when it crashes?

Comment: See the edited post!

Comment: I always have added my contraints via the Storyboard, but in your code shouldnt your constraints have a `toItem` parameter, being the `self.view'?

Comment: Also, what are you trying to do, make the map bigger? smaller? What size is it currently showing as in the app?

Comment: I want to make the map to be as big as the screen on all devices but also be able to change the size to for example half of the screen.

Comment: Setting toItem to self.view crashed the app.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you should use

```
self.mapView.addConstraint(widthConstraint)
```

and

```
self.mapView.addConstraint(heightConstraint)
```

You are trying to add a constraint that belongs to the mapView to its superview, that's not the way it's supposed to be. If you were adding a vertical distance between the mapview and another view you would add it to the superview, but not in this case.

Answer (score 0):

For the constraint warning you try to add constraint without disabling the autorisizing mask into constraint translation.

Try adding this line:

```
mapView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

Regards